# Enviar mail desde phpMailer con Angular 16

Tags: php, angular, phpmailer

Tengo un problema con phpMailer y Angular, estuve toda la semana pasada buscando la solución pero no pude dar con ella. Mi aplicación web está construida con Angular 16. La idea es con un formulario de contacto, enviar un mail. Cuando levanto la aplicación en el servidor (estoy usando xampp) no me envía el mail. Estoy usando composer que me genera el vendor de phpmailer.

- Primero probé directamente teniendo el archivo index.php que tiene la llamada a mailer directamente en la misma carpeta - cuando ejecuto en el form me encuentra index.php pero no envía el mail. Pensé un problema de rutas en el index.php llamando a phpMailer y funciones, modifique eso, hasta las pase a la misma carpeta- no funciono.
- Después arme un servicio en Angular para llamar al archivo php. Vi que otras personas lo hacia, tampoco. Tengo el problema de que encuentra el archivo pero no lo envia.

Para levantar la aplicación en xampp tengo que hacer el build primero. La carpeta vendor y index.php los dejo fuera del build. El archivo php funciona si lo pruebo con un componente html común, o sea me hago un formulario.html, el index.php, la carpeta vender y todo fantástico, el problema es cuando construyo la aplicación Angular, ya no sé si es un problema de verificación, de rutas, no sé, encima no me da errores que pueda rastrear. Espero alguien me ilumine y me ayude a pensar cómo resolverlo. Mil gracias Mi formulario (en el onSubmit no hago más que mostrar una notificación por el momento)

```html
<div class="container" >  
  <form id="contact"  method="POST" action="index.php"   >
    <h3>Para mas información, le pedimos 
      que por favor complete el formulario.</h3>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Nombre y apellido" type="text" tabindex="1" [formControl]="nombreControl" class="form-control nombre" name="nombre" required [(ngModel)]="nombre">
      <span *ngIf="nombreControl?.touched && !nombreControl.valid" class="error">
       Ingresa nombre y apellido
      </span>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Empresa:" type="text" tabindex="2" [formControl]="empresaControl" class="form-control empresa" [(ngModel)]="empresa" name="empresa" required>
      <span *ngIf="empresaControl?.touched && !empresaControl.valid" class="error">
        Nombre de tu empresa
       </span>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Teléfono" type="tel" tabindex="3"  [formControl]="telefonoControl" class="form-control telefono" name="telefono" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset >
      <input placeholder="Mail" type="email" tabindex="4"  [formControl]="emailControl" name="email" required class="form-control mail"  [(ngModel)]="email" >
      <span *ngIf="emailControl?.touched && !emailControl.valid" class="error">
       Ingresa tu email <br/>
       </span>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <textarea placeholder="Mensaje" tabindex="5"  [formControl]="mensajeControl"  class="form-control textarea"  [(ngModel)]="mensaje" name="mensaje" required ></textarea> 
      <span *ngIf="mensajeControl?.touched && !mensajeControl.valid" class="error">
        Ingresa tu consulta
        </span>
    </fieldset> 
    <div class="container-buttons">
      <div class="forms-buttons">
          <label>
            <button name="submit" type="submit"  data-submit="...Sending" [disabled]="!nombreControl.valid || !empresaControl.valid || !emailControl.valid || !mensajeControl.valid"  (click)="onSubmit($event)" >Enviar</button>
          </label>
          <label for="">
              <button name="delete" type="reset" >Borrar todo</button>
          </label>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Index.php

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');

use vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer;
use vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\SMTP;
use vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $empresa = $_POST["empresa"];
    $telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"];

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;  
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';                    //Enable verbose debug output con 0 se desactiva, protocolo seguridad
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.ejemplo.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'ejemplo@ejemplo.com';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = ******';                               //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port       = 465;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

  
    $mail->setFrom('ejemplo@ejemplo.com');
    $mail->addAddress('ejemplo@ejemplo.com');         
      addAddress('otro@ejemplo.com');
        
    Contenido
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
    $mail->Subject = 'Asunto: ' . $empresa;
    $mail->Body = 'Nombre: ' . $nombre . '<br>' .
                  'Teléfono: ' . $telefono . '<br>' .
                  'Mail: ' . $mail->Username . '<br>' .
                  'Mensaje: ' . $mensaje;

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Mensaje enviado correctamente';
    
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error al enviar: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: primero que nada el codigo php es incorrecto ... te tas comiendo un poco de comillas en las variables que son de texto y pareciera que fuera un copy paste de algun ejemplo... ante todo verifica las credenciales, si el correo es de gmail requeriras implementar el metodo de autenticacion por aplicaciones de tercero. ya que gmail elimino el metodo directo smtp...

Comment: por otro lado, si estas usando angular tienes que validar que realmente angular este llamando al servicio, tiened que hacer debug, no con enviar un correo, si no validar con un output de ejemplo que angular esta llegando a ese archivo de php.

Comment: otra cosa que puedes hacer, si estas seguro que tu angular es alcansando el archivo php es verificar si hay algun mensaje de error por pantalla, consola de javascript o log del servidor xampp

Comment: Pudiste resolverlo??? Yo estoy en la misma situación, nunca programé en PHP y necesito desplegar mi App, y cuando envío los datos no sale ningun error por consola, ni tampoco en el inspector del navegador... y en el servicio de Angular ya verifiqué y le estoy apuntando bien al directorio en donde está mi archivo .php